# Обработка данных внутри таблицы с применением штатных средств postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задача следующая:

Определение основного магазина клиента. Для каждого клиента определяется его основной магазин. В случае, если три последние транзакции совершены в одном и том же магазине, в качестве основного магазина клиента устанавливает этот магазин. В ином случае в качестве основного магазина клиента указывается магазин, в котором совершена наибольшая доля всех транзакций клиента. В случае, если для нескольких магазинов указана одинаковая доля транзакций, в качестве основного магазина выбирается тот из них, в которым была совершена самая поздняя транзакция. Получившееся значение указывается в поле Customer_Primary_Store таблицы Клиенты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT
    PD.customer_id,TR.transaction_datetime, TR.transaction_store_id,
    sum(TR.transaction_summ) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id) / count(TR.transaction_summ) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id),
    count(TR.transaction_id) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id, TR.transaction_store_id)::numeric /
    count(TR.transaction_id) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id)::numeric AS KKK,
    lead(TR.transaction_store_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id ORDER BY TR.transaction_datetime DESC),
    lead(TR.transaction_store_id, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id ORDER BY TR.transaction_datetime DESC)
FROM Personal_Data AS PD
JOIN Cards AS CR ON PD.customer_id = CR.customer_id
JOIN Transactions AS TR ON TR.customer_card_id = CR.customer_card_id
ORDER BY customer_id, transaction_datetime desc
```

Не могу подобрать необходимую оконную функцию. 2 lead использую для определения последующих записей для сравнения. А вот вторая часть задания я так понимаю в case нужно описать?

---

Решение:

```
WITH maininfo AS
         (SELECT PD.customer_id                               AS "CI",
                 TR.transaction_datetime                      AS "TD",
                 TR.transaction_store_id                      AS "TSI",

                 sum(TR.transaction_summ) OVER w_pci::float /
                 count(TR.transaction_summ) OVER w_pci::float AS "ATS",

                 row_number() OVER w_pci_otd_d                AS rn,
                 count(*) OVER w_pcitsi                       AS cnt

          FROM Personal_Data AS PD
                   JOIN Cards AS CR ON PD.customer_id = CR.customer_id
                   JOIN Transactions AS TR ON TR.customer_card_id = CR.customer_card_id
              WINDOW w_pci AS (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id),
                  w_pcitsi AS (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id, TR.transaction_store_id),
                  w_pci_otd_d AS (PARTITION BY PD.customer_id ORDER BY TR.transaction_datetime DESC)),
     cte2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT "CI",
                              first_value("TSI") OVER (PARTITION BY "CI" ORDER BY cnt DESC, "TD" DESC) AS preferred_shop,
                              first_value("TSI") OVER (PARTITION BY "CI" ORDER BY rn ASC)              AS last_shop
              FROM maininfo),
     cte3 AS (SELECT "CI",
                     COUNT(DISTINCT "TSI") last_3_cnt
              FROM maininfo
              WHERE rn <= 3
              GROUP BY "CI")

SELECT "Customer_ID",
       "Customer_Average_Check",
       "Customer_Average_Check_Segment",
       "Customer_Frequency",
       "Customer_Frequency_Segment",
       "Customer_Inactive_Period",
       "Customer_Churn_Rate",
       "Customer_Churn_Segment",
       Segment AS "Segment",

       CASE
           WHEN last_3_cnt = 1 THEN last_shop
           ELSE preferred_shop
           END AS Customer_Primary_Store

FROM (SELECT "Customer_ID",
             "Customer_Average_Check",

             CASE
                 WHEN (percent_rank() OVER w_ocac_d < 0.1) THEN 'High'
                 WHEN (percent_rank() OVER w_ocac_d < 0.35) THEN 'Medium'
                 ELSE 'Low'
                 END                                           AS "Customer_Average_Check_Segment",

             "Customer_Frequency",

             CASE
                 WHEN (percent_rank() OVER w_ocf < 0.1) THEN 'Often'
                 WHEN (percent_rank() OVER w_ocf < 0.35) THEN 'Occasionally'
                 ELSE 'Rarely'
                 END                                           AS "Customer_Frequency_Segment",

             "Customer_Inactive_Period",

             "Customer_Inactive_Period" / "Customer_Frequency" AS "Customer_Churn_Rate",

             CASE
                 WHEN ("Customer_Inactive_Period" / "Customer_Frequency" < 2) THEN 'Low'
                 WHEN ("Customer_Inactive_Period" / "Customer_Frequency" < 5) THEN 'Medium'
                 ELSE 'High'
                 END                                           AS "Customer_Churn_Segment"

      FROM (SELECT "CI"                                    AS "Customer_ID",
                   "ATS"                                   AS "Customer_Average_Check",

                   extract(EPOCH from max("TD") - min("TD"))::float / 86400.0 /
                   count("CI")                             AS "Customer_Frequency",

                   extract(EPOCH from '21.08.2022 0:00:00'::timestamp -
                                      max("TD")) / 86400.0 AS "Customer_Inactive_Period"
            FROM maininfo
            GROUP BY "CI", "ATS"
                WINDOW w_oats_d AS (ORDER BY sum("ATS") DESC)) AS avmain
      GROUP BY "Customer_ID",
               "Customer_Average_Check",
               "Customer_Frequency",
               "Customer_Inactive_Period"
          WINDOW w_ocac_d AS (ORDER BY sum("Customer_Average_Check") DESC),
              w_ocf AS (ORDER BY "Customer_Frequency")) AS biginfo
         JOIN Segments AS S ON S.Average_Check = "Customer_Average_Check_Segment" AND
                               S.Purchase_Frequency = "Customer_Frequency_Segment" AND
                               S.Churn_Probability = "Customer_Churn_Segment"
         JOIN cte2 ON cte2."CI" = biginfo."Customer_ID"
         JOIN cte3 ON cte3."CI" = biginfo."Customer_ID"
```

Comment: *без применения внешних функций* - вот что означает эта фраза?

Comment: @Akina          Только функциями агрегации и оконными функциями

Comment: Так бы и писал - использовать только штатные средства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY pay_date DESC) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, shop_id) cnt
  FROM payments
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         user_id,
         FIRST_VALUE(shop_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY cnt DESC, pay_date DESC) preferred_shop,
         FIRST_VALUE(shop_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY rn ASC) last_shop
  FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT user_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT shop_id) last_3_cnt
  FROM cte1
  WHERE rn <= 3
  GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN last_3_cnt = 1 THEN last_shop ELSE preferred_shop END base_shop
FROM cte2
JOIN cte3 USING (user_id)
ORDER BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YjtscdRs)

Пояснения (fiddle показывает вычисления по шагам).

- `cte1` нумерует покупки, начиная с новых, чтобы определить последние 3, а также считает количество покупок для каждого магазина, чтобы определить, в каком сделано больше всего покупок.
- `cte2` определяет предпочтительный магазин (тот, в котором сделано больше всего покупок, а если таких с одинаковым числом покупок несколько - то тот, в котором сделана самая последняя из них), а также магазин, в котором сделана самая последняя покупка.
- `cte3` считает, в скольких магазинах сделаны последние 3 покупки.
- Основной запрос выводит нужные данные. Если все 3 последние покупки сделаны в одном магазине - выводится этот магазин (вернее, тот, в котором сделана последняя покупка, но это одно и то же). Если же 3 последние покупки сделаны в разных магазинах, выводится тот, в котором сделано больше всего покупок, а если таких несколько - тот, в котором сделана последняя из этих покупок.

PS. Само собой, в `cte1` вместо таблицы `payments` следует использовать соотв. набор связанных таблиц, который предоставит необходимые данные.

PPS. Подставив правильный источник данных, не делайте `SELECT *` в `cte1`, выберите только реально необходимые 3 поля. Это я могу поставить звезду в модели, потому что лишних полей в таблице-источнике просто нет.

Comment: Есл будет возможность посмотреть моё решение, буду очень рад. Начинаю писать маленькие скрипты и хотелось бы в начале пути вытравить все ошибки использования postgresql

Comment: @Astrodynamic Любое решение реализует некую логику действий. Я вот эту логику подробно расписал. А насчёт Вашего решения - вот нет у меня никакого желания разбираться в том, что там наверчено... распишите подробно, тогда будем смотреть, соответствует запрос заданию или нет.